# Change private variable value inside interface implementation

Tags: java, interface, access-modifiers

I'm having trouble changing the value of a private variable ( of the class who implements the interface) that is inside the interface implementation.

I have an interface **IClient**:

```
public interface IClient{

    void showNewArticles(Article a);
}
```

and a class **Client** who implements the **IClient**:

```
public class Client implements IClient{

 ( .... )

 private DefaultListModel<String> listModelArticles = new DefaultListModel<>();

 ( .... )

 @Override
 public void showNewArticles(Article a){

     String infoArticle = ("["+a.getKeyword().toUpperCase()+"] "+a.getTitle());

     listModelArticles.addElement(infoArticle);
     listArticles.setModel(listModelArticles);
 }

}
```

The problem is that when I execute the `showNewArticles()` method, it doesn't add  an element in the `listModelArticles`, but if I create a private or public method (inside the Client class ) and execute `listModelArticles.addElement(infoArticles)` inside it, the infoArticle is inserted into the model correctly. Is something to do with the access modifiers?

Comment: `it doesn't add an element in the listModelArticles` How do you know? In either case, how are you determining the size of `listModelArticles`?

Comment: `Is something to do with the access modifiers?` definitely no

Comment: @copeg I checked the ``listModelArticles`` content in the debuger. Sorry, I wrote the wrong line at the beginning of the Client class. It isn't ``listModelSubscriptions``, is ``listModelArticles``.

Comment: Where does `listArticles` come from? What is it? I don't see where it comes from. By the way, what is the name of the interface? `IClient` or `IClientGUI`?

Comment: I'm confused.  Essentially, what `addElement` on `listModelArticles` boils down to is adding a string.  Are you telling us that you can't add a string into that object?  How do you know you're not seeing what you expect?  There's not much we can infer with the sliver of information you've provided us here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was a problem with the class that call the the IClient method of the Client class. Thanks to everyone who tried to solve my problem :)

My solution:

```
@Override
public void showNewArticles(Article a) throws RemoteException {

   IClient client = MainController.getInstance().getClient();
   client.showNewArticles(a);
}
```

Before the solution:

```
@Override
public void showNewArticles(Article a) throws RemoteException {

  ClientI.getInstance().showNewArticles(a);
}
```

I don't know why it wasn't working before, though I was using Singleton. But now it works.